# how to select models where an attribute is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really do apologise for the simplicity of this question- I seem to be having some sort of memory lapse!

If models.where(:colour => 'green').count gives the number of models with colour attribute green, how do I count the number of models which have a colour at all?

models.where(:colour => true).count clearly not right...

Thanks in advance for any help on this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
models.where("colour IS NOT NULL").count
```